# Background image not showing in nested divs

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where I my background image isn't showing in a specific circumstance, and when it does there are some issues.

```html
<div id="indHeader">

    <div id=" indImg">
      content goes here
    </div><!-- end of  indHeader-->
  </div> <!-- end of indImg-->
```

If I have the div ids swapped, the image shows as normal - the issue being it gets messed up when messing with the size of the page (the image reduces in size, but there is a growing margin like space above the image. The width remains 100%, but the height does not.) If I have it as it is in the above code, the background image does not show at all.

```css
#indImg {
    background-image: url("../images/index_header.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Would there be a way to have the background show in the indImg div, or to not have it move when adjusting the size of the page? If I remove the background-size style, it somewhat fixes it but then the image does not fit 100% of the browser width. Adjusting background-position changes where the height changes, e.g removing the current property makes the image go to the top, not the bottom.

[Image sort of showing what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDrp4.png)

Comment: What is the proportion of the image? You have to take it in consideration. Or maybe use a `<img>` tag? And what are the dimensions of the #indImg element?

Comment: I seem to be having some success with the below, but now the image gets bad resolution when resized.
position: relative;
    background-image: url(file...);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100vh;

Comment: Image is 1600 x 477, would it be best to simply find another image?

Comment: It depends. Did you try to use `background-size: cover` to see how it goes?

Comment: Ah, thank you! Cover works almost perfectly, just need to find a better image that will work to stop something like this happening (https://i.imgur.com/larsO2d.png), or could do a media query to move the position of the image when it shrinks, I guess. But the functionality working over the prettiness is really appreciated. 

Thanks a bunch, that really helped :)

Can you please comment so I can select you as the answer?

Comment: Yes, this image in specific is too wide. There are several approaches from there. Good luck. Comments cannot be selected as answer. Don't worry about that.